# Не работает счётчик баллов Python

Tags: python

При каждом правильном ответе, в переменной result должны суммироваться и сохраняться добавленные балы. Но при каждом чтении строк из текстового документа, переменная result обнуляется.
Суть моего задания создать программу, которая выводит слова из текстового документа в виде теста, и при этом перемешивая буквы в них, а пользователь в свою очередь должен отгадать выведенное слово.
И в конце теста, программа должна вывести количество набранных баллов за правильные ответы.
У меня есть два предположения почему и откуда берутся ноги у моей проблемы.

1. Вероятно проблема в переменной lines в которой прописано "file.readlines()" из за которого программа считывает весь текстовый документ разом.
2. Ну или же проблема в условии "if word == read_word[:-1]:" Но как сделать по другому чтобы в функцию строки текст-дока входили поочерёдно, я не знаю.

```
def test_verification(word, read_word):
    score = 0
    start = True
    while start:
        if word == read_word[:-1]:
            print("Программа: Верно! вы получаете 10 очков.")
            score += 10
        elif word != read_word:
            print(f"Неверно! Верный ответ - {read_word}.")
        print(score)
        start = False


def random_words(random_word):
    import random
    text = random_word
    words = text.split()
    for i, word in enumerate(map(list, words)):
        random.shuffle(word)
        words[i] = ''.join(word)
    return words


with open('words.txt', 'r+') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    login = input('Программа: Введите ваше имя : ')
    active = True
    while active:
        for line in lines:
            question1 = line
            response_1 = input(f"Программа: Угадайте слово:  {random_words(random_word=line)}\n")
            test_verification(word=response_1, read_word=question1)
            print()
        active = False
```

Comment: Но у вас нет переменной result...

Comment: И непонятно, зачем вам циклы `while`, если они написаны так, что срабатывают всегда ровно один раз. Вам бы разобраться - что вы вообще делаете и зачем. А по сути - возвращайте `score` из функции `test_verification`, да добавляйте его в `result`, который предварительно заведите равным 0. Вот вам и будет суммарный скор.